When were U.S. political parties realigned?
Robert F. Kennedy, Jr., in his interview with Tucker Carlson (@1:17), says:

There's been a bunch of realignments (about 4 or 5) throughout American history; and I think we're going through one right now, with the Democratic Party and with both political parties really changing in a very dramatic way.

What were these "4 or 5" political party "realignments" in U.S. history?

One was presumably the Southern Strategy of the Republican Party.

This looks like it might be completely answered on the Wikipedia page for Political Eras in the United States. Is that good enough? I suppose I could digest it down a bit (might be nice to have that here to refer people to).

@T.E.D. I think a summary of the four Wikipedia pages you are referring to would be useful here. My most recent American History and civics classes date to the early 1980s. Until today I had never heard of the First thru Seventh Party System, and I would not have known how to locate relevant information in Wikipedia.

All questions should explain why WIkipedia is insufficient.  If you don't at least copy the  question and paste into google, you haven't done basic, preliminary research.  Make an effort to find an answer before asking the question.

There have been 6 political party regimes in US History since the inception of the US Constitution. This of course means there were 5 party realignments in between them, with another possibly ongoing now. These regimes are commonly called "party systems", and given numbers in chronological order. These are roughly:*

First Party System: 1790's-1824ish


Average state election results, 1792-1816. Federalists in brown, Democratic-Republicans green.

Second Party System : 1828-1852


Average state election results, 1828-1852

Third Party System : 1850's-1890's


Average election results, 1856-1896. Green states voted for the Populist Party

Fourth Party System : 1896ish-1932


Average election results, 1896-1928

Fifth Party System : 1932-(opinions range between 1962 and 1980)


Average election results, 1932-1960, then during the realignment from 1964-1976

Sixth Party System : (1962 to 1980)-Present day?


Average election results, 1980-2020
All this adds up to the following "realignments":

The initial alignment. This came about due to disputes among the founders, particularly in President Washington's cabinet, about backing the power of a strong Federal Government (Federalists) vs. State and personal freedoms (Democratic-Republicans). After the establishment of the French Republic, this largely turned into a foreign policy dispute on whether to support England or France respectively

With the War of 1812 the pro-England Federalist position became much more unpopular, and the peace thereafter made the whole England-vs-France dispute seem less important, so the Federalist party just sort of petered out. There were no real parties in the election of 1824. However, one of the losers of that election, the populist Andrew Jackson, was so incensed that he rebuilt his followers into an organized force that managed to win him the next election. This group became known as the Democratic Party. The anti-Jackson voters formed their own organization that became known as the "Whigs".

During the 1840's slavery became the nation's biggest issue. The Democratic party of course fully supported it, but the Whig party had trouble coming to a unified decision. Given the importance of the issue, this eventually ripped the party apart, on its way to doing the same to the nation. The nation thankfully survived, but the Whig party did not. By 1856 it had ceased to exist. One of its successors, the Republican Party, won the 1860 election. The US Civil War ensued, along with the next (third) party system.

A bad "Panic" (trading market bubble-induced economic depression) in 1893 discredited the incumbent Democratic party outside the Jim Crow region, and within that region empowered the Democratic party's more populist elements. This settled down in 1896 to what we call the fourth Party System

The Great Depression (also trading market bubble-induced) broke the power of the Republican Party and discredited their hands-off economic philosophy, particularly in the big industrial cities in the Northeast and Midwest where millions were thrown out of work.

The support of the national Democratic Party for the Civil Rights movement caused the supporters of the "Jim Crow" racial caste system in the South to start looking for other options, starting particularly with the election of 1964, where most of the "solid south" were the only states to vote for the Republican. Their historic antipathy toward "The party of Lincoln" probably caused this process to take longer than it otherwise would have, but by 1980 the movement of this White Supremacist faction into the Republican party was essentially complete (at least at the national level).

? - The nature of this way of organizing party systems is that its much easier to tell it happened in distant retrospect than it is while its happening. That's probably why opinions vary so widely on when the 5th system ended, and also why they vary even more widely if the 6th is still going on, or a realignment is happening right now, or perhaps one has already happened. In the words of the Magic 8-Ball: Reply Hazy. Ask again later.



* - Where not stated, the colors use the modern standard of blue for Democrats, red for Republicans. The darker the color, the more often that state awarded its electors to that party's Presidential nominee. Gray indicates a tie for the period.
